# how to compare two variables of a object in arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, duplicates

I have a pojo with variables brand,type and date, I created a Arraylist using this pojo. This arraylist is having duplicates, now i want to remove duplicates from the arraylist by comparing only brand and type of that object. if brand and type are already exists,I need to remove that object from arraylist.

Comment: can you have a code snippet or code sample ?

Comment: Override equals() & hahscode() and use list1.removeAll(list2)

Comment: Implement `equals()` to declare two objects equal if they have the same brand and type (don’t look at date). As a consequence, `hashCode()` should not look at date either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `equals()` and `hashCode()` of the added class according to your variable, then use **LinkedHashSet** instead of **ArrayList** and all your work will be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable or unwilling to change the `equals()` method of the POJO, then you will have to use a Map to collect one sample for each distinct brand+type pair.

Here is an example code snippet that does this using a stream:

```
    list = new ArrayList(list.stream().unordered()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    pojo -> new Pair<>(pojo.brand, pojo.type),
                    pojo -> pojo,
                    (original, duplicate) -> original)).values());
```

Alternatively, you could wrap each POJO in a wrapper object which defines `equals` based only on brand and type, then use the simpler `distinct()` stream filter, and finally unwrap each result.